# Blank page when call form helper CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, libraries

Before I added form helper I get all result and without error.
 But, when I call form helper I just get blank page without error. 

Controller Script:

```
class Reza extends CI_Controller
 {

  function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library(array("rez_lib"));
   }
  function index(){
    $this->rez_lib->display("home");
  }
}
```

library Script:

```
class Rez_lib
 {
  protected $_ci;
  function __construct(){
     $this->_ci =& get_instance();
  }
  function display($temp, $data=null){

    $data['header'] = $this->_ci->load->view("construct/header",$data,true);
    $data['sidebar'] = $this->_ci->load-    >view("construct/sidebar",$data,true);
    $data['content']  = $this->_ci->load->view("page/".$temp,$data,true);
    $this->_ci->load->view("construct/all",$data,true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is form helper loaded? Where is it used?

Comment: You should activate errors on PHP. Change the values in index.php to (caution, this should be done only in development): `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and then post the error messages.

Comment: you are saying helper ! but you are loading a library in the actual code ? clarify correctly.

Comment: i loaded helper at autoload file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off the blank screen is because you do not have debugging enabled.
Go to index.php and set the 'ENVIRONMENT' constant to 'development' when developing.

Secondly it seems you have several typos in your library class.

1. In your constructor you have an extra space between & and get_instance(): `$this->_ci =& get_instance();`
2. In your class body you also have an extra space between load- and ->view (when loading your sidebar) `$data['sidebar'] = $this->_ci->load-    >view("construct/sidebar",$data,true);`

Finally you are returning the view as data, since the third parameter is set to true. See:

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the method so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to TRUE (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html